# SSAS large dimension

Tags: ssas, cube

I have a SSAS cube in which one of my dimension has 5 million recrods. When I try to view data for the dimension, report or excel pivot becomes lengthy and also the performance is poor. I cant categorize that particular dimension data. Only way I can think of to restrict data is select top 10K rows from the dimension which has metric values. Apart from restricting it to top 10K dimension records can anyone please suggest other possibilities?

Comment: possible duplicate of [million rows dimension in ssas cube](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10592439/million-rows-dimension-in-ssas-cube)

Answer (score 0):

Have you set up aggregations?  I would venture to guess that the majority of the time being spent getting your data to a viewing point has to do with your measures.  If I was you I would try adding in aggregations or upping the aggregation percent in order to alleviate some of the pressure at querytime by passing this workload to the processing time of the dimension/cube.

Generally, people set their aggregation levels at about 30% to start.

If you have done this already, I would think about upgrading your hardware on the server that your cube sits on.  (depending on what you already have)

These are just suggestions as it could also be an issue in your cube design that is causing a lengthy runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to create a hierarchy for showing 5 million records. Group by substring in Level 1,( if required some characters in Level 2), then the data falling under that group. For example :

```
Level 1           Value
A                 Apple
A                 Ant
```

This would mean that you wont be showing all 5 million records at once and it is very effective now to use aggregations too.