# million rows dimension in ssas cube

Tags: ssas, olap, cube, ssas-2008, cube-dimension

I have a large dimension in my cube which has 5 million rows. when I drag that dimension column in excel to view metric value it times out. Is there any way I can limit the data dynamically or selecting only top 10K rows when that large dimension is pulled in excel? or any other best approch?

Answer (score 4):

you shouldn't allow the attribute to be browsed. Think about, who will look for a particular row among 5 million others?

The best practice in this case, and that's not me saying I heard from a Microsoft MVP, its to add the attribute to a Hierarchy and set the `AttributeHierarchyVisible` property to false. It will hide the attribute from the end user. You can still use it on MDX and it still appears in hierarchies, you just cant browse it alone.